# Datepicker Javascript not fetching tomorrow's date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I want select start date as today's date and end date as tommorrow's date. I am getting start date as today's date (which is correct) but I am getting end date as `12/31/1969`. Here's the piece of code:

```
$("#endOnDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    minDate: new Date()
});
$("#startOnDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#endOnDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just have a radio input for "today" and "tomorrow" - 2 days in a datepicker seems overkill

Comment: Appears to work fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nxs2j91f/

Answer (score 0):

Plz updateas followes.I have modified it plz find

```
$("#endOnDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", minDate: new Date()});

$("#startOnDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", minDate: new Date(), 
   onSelect: function (dateText) {

            var actualDate = new Date(dateText);
         var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(),          actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+1);
       alert('fff'+newDate);
            $("#endOnDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);
        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past I managed the start and end date picker to build my own select range valid. So I wish to suggest you:

```
 $( "#startOnDate" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            maxDate: new Date(),
            onSelect: function(selected) {
                $("#endOnDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
            }
        }).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
        $( "#endOnDate" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            minDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
            onSelect: function(selected) {
                $("#startOnDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
            }
        }).datepicker('setDate', new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Could you try and let me know? thanks
To initialize the datepicker i added some code. Could you try now and let me know? Thanks

Comment: The calendar is showing April 2015 but the date inside the input box is still 12/31/1969 .Initially it was showing 1969 calendar.

Comment: i changed my script adding a default date for both fields